# Java IDE Plugin or external tool (ant, maven, standalone) that convert bbcode to javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc, bbcode

I want to format some part of my javadocs with a simpler syntax than the basic html we have to use (for things like bold and italic, also for paragraph and code).

Is anybody knows a tool that let me use a kind of bbcode syntax in my source and will transform those bbcode comments into valid javadoc comments ?

It could be an IDE plugin, a pre-compile ant task or even a stand alone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own doclet to translate from your bbcode/javadoc format to the standard javadoc HTML format. Writing a doclet is easy - see http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/ as a start.  Parsing BBCode might be possible using https://javabbcode.dev.java.net/